# Having trouble linking a library in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

.pro file...

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ASIGUI
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -L"libs/cxcore.lib" \
            -L"libs/highgui.lib" \
            -L"libs/ASICamera.lib" \

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    liveview.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    liveview.h \
    asicamera.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I got this same exact program working just fine in Visual Studio, but I'm new to Qt, and I getting the following error for every function I call that's contained in the .lib files...

`liveview.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCreateImage referenced in function "public: void __cdecl liveview::Start(void)" (?Start@liveview@@QEAAXXZ)`

I've read many answers on here already, but can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Visual Studio with Qt Add-in using the same `.pro` file?

Comment: Isn't `cvCreateImage` part of OpenCV? Does Qt Creator have a way of letting you specify additional library paths and libraries?

Comment: @LogicStuff I did it in VS using `Project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`

Comment: @birryree Two of the libraries are part of OpenCV I believe. I'm just following the SDK's test project.

Answer (score 0):

Like in any C++ project, you have to say where the libraries are with `-L` and then, what libraries you want to use.
I am assuming you have included all needed libraries and `libs` is in the right place, so You should change:

```
LIBS += -L"libs/cxcore.lib" \
-L"libs/highgui.lib" \
-L"libs/ASICamera.lib" \
```

for

```
LIBS += -Llibs \
cxcore.lib \
highgui.lib \
ASICamera.lib
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I do that, I get an error saying cannot find file.

Comment: Then perhaps you don't have the file? Or are indicating a wrong path?

Comment: You dont have that library file, no proper path or lack of paths.

Comment: The way I originally had linked fine. I could hold ctrl and click the paths, and it'll open the files. it won't do that when I try it the second way. The files are most certainly there.